# CP-SAT Optimizing Consumer With Dynamic Efficiency

Tags: performance, optimization, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I'm trying to optimize the power consumption of a consumer over a period of time (step-by-step) with Google OR Tools CP-SAT Solver.

The challenge is, that the output of the consumer depends on the ratio of consumable amount of energy and maximum energy consumption. (efficiency)

Able to calculate the ratio for each time step

`model.Add(ratio[time] == LinearExpr.Prod(Power[time], (int)(1 / maxPowerValue) * 100));`

Now, I need to read the consumbale energy amount for the ratio (between 0...100) finding itself stored in a

`IntVarArray[time][ratio-value]`

As expected it is not possible to just enter

`ratio[time]`

for the ratio-value index.

The resulting maximum energy amount should then act as a new constraint (upper-bound) for the power consumed. (Is circling constraints even possible in that way?)

Did anyone face a similar problem or can you push me into the right direction with this?

Cheers

Comment: Can you simplify the problem saying that both demand and duration are a function of start time ?

Comment: Not as far as I can see right now. The demand is related to losses due to different outdoor temperatures and the time steps length is constant.